# Samsung S4 Video record using native camera issue

Tags: android, android-camera, video-capture, samsung-mobile

I am working on an application where user can capture a video using the phone's default camera. For that I have used the following intent

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE).putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, maxLimit), Constants.INTENT_ID_RECORD_VIDEO);
```

It works fine in Samsung galaxy nexus, Lg nexus 4, Lenovo 260 etc. Upon launching the intent, in the above devices the camera opens in video mode and user can start recording the video directly, but in Samsung S4 device the camera opens in a mode where user has to again select video mode and then start recording.

Is there a way that it can be avoided. 
Can any of you please provide any work around?

Please point me to any valid official documentation if this is an issue that can not be resolved.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have access to this Samsung S4 device? Maybe there is some 3rd party Camera app installed as the default handler for VIDEO_CAPTURE intent?

Comment: No it is opening the app that is by default in the device, the camera application of the device only, i am sure.